# How do I optimize my code to run with n <= 100 and a,b <= 10^5?

Tags: python-3.x, math

#How do I optimize my code to run with n <= 100 and a,b <= 10^5?

Here's the question

There are N test cases, each test case enters 2 integers a and b, summing all digits from a to b
*Input:*

- The first line is N
- For the next N lines, enter the numbers a, b

*Output* is N lines with N results of the problem

Sample:

Input:

```
2
5 12
12 60
```

Output:

```
41
378
```

Note: At the first test case, we have the sum = 5+6+7+8+9+1+0+1+1+1+2 = 41

Here is my code, but it got Time Limit Exceeded

```
def main():
    def tonga(a):
        tong = 0
        while a > 0:
            tong += a % 10
            a //= 10
        return tong
    def main1():
        a, b = map(int, input().split())
        tong = 0
        for z in range(a, b + 1):
            if z < 10:
                tong += z
            else:
                tong += tonga(z)
        print(tong)
    n = int(input())
    for _ in range(n):
        main1()
main()
```

Comment: With python, a lot of the optimization is about trying to not do calculations in python. For example, explicit loops would be "in python" and are typically slower than implicit loops like `map` and `range` which are written in a faster language like c. The cost gets changed from interpreting code to just making a call. See: `sum(map(int,''.join(map(str,range(5,13)))))`

Comment: @Ouroborus your suggestion makes a single case fast, but the question is to make up to 100 cases fast. The original problem's purpose is I guess to improve algorithm skills: there's two obvious algorithmic tricks which might apply -- one is to do running sums, the other is to do a digit-by-digit sum to compute the range sum in O(log(b-a)) time (which is much fiddlier, and given the range of the numbers not the target solution). It would be clearer which solution was intended if N was much larger, or the upper range of a and b was much larger.

Comment: @PaulHankin On the other hand, these puzzle sites often have a discussion that gets unlocked once you manage to solve the puzzle. It did occur to me that precomputing is likely a better solution, but I'm also against "I did it for you" answers, especially for these kind of questions. (Never mind that a brief search turned up many results offering a solution for this puzzle.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute the running sum of digits from 0 to each number up to 10^5. For example:

```
A = [0] * 100001
for i in range(1, 100001):
    A[i] = A[i-1] + sum(int(d) for d in str(i))
```

Now, for each `a` and `b`, you can compute the sum of the digit sums from `a` to `b` in O(1) time: it's simply `A[b] - A[a-1]`.

For a solution that works without precomputation (for example if the input range is much larger than 10^5), you can find the sum of the digits from all the numbers from 1 to N in O((logN)^2) arithmetic operations. Based on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/817038/sum-of-digits-of-number-from-1-to-n

```
def dss(a):
    T, M = 0, 1
    while a > 0:
        q, r = a // 10, a % 10
        T += M * (45 * q + (r+1)*r//2 + (r+1)*sum(map(int, str(q))))
        a, M = q - 1, M*10
    return T

def dig_sum_range(a, b):
    return dss(b) - dss(a-1)

print(dig_sum_range(1, 1000000000000))
```

Comment: Still got time limit exceed, but i will try to improve it !!

Answer (score -1):

Since all the digits that need to be summed are in the range from 1 to 9. Instead of recalculating the sum of digits for each number every time, you could try to precalculate and store those values to save resources.

```
def main():
    def sum_digits(n):
        return sum(map(int, str(n)))

    # Precalculate the sum of digits for numbers 1 to 9
    single_digits_sum = [sum_digits(i) for i in range(1, 10)]

    def sum_range(a, b):
        # Calculate the sum of digits for the range from a to b
        range_sum = 0

        # Add the sum of digits for numbers in the range [a, b]
        for i in range(a, b + 1):
            range_sum += single_digits_sum[i % 10]

        return range_sum

    n = int(input())
    for _ in range(n):
        a, b = map(int, input().split())
        result = sum_range(a, b)
        print(result)

main()
```

Comment: this got List Index Out of range at the test, i think u missed something